# Random number generation differences between gcc 4.8.5 and gcc 8.1.0

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

The following test code produces different results when compiled with gcc 4.8.5 vs gcc 8.1.0:

```
// test.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
        std::mt19937_64 rand_gen(1);
        int n_combos = 5;
        std::vector<size_t> indices(n_combos);
        for (size_t i=0; i<n_combos; ++i)
                indices[i] = i;

        std::shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), rand_gen);
        for(auto elem: indices)
                std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

**GCC 4.8.5:**

```
[brock@localhost]$ /usr/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[brock@localhost]$ /usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o printrandom.exe
[brock@localhost]$ ./printrandom.exe 
4, 3, 1, 0, 2,
```

**GCC 8.1.0:**

```
[brock@localhost]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[brock@localhost]$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o printrandom.exe
[brock@localhost]$ ./printrandom.exe 
3, 0, 4, 2, 1,
```

Why do they produce different results for the same seeded number generator and/or how do I find out why they are different? I suspect an implementation difference somewhere.

Comment: Compile with `-S` and check the emitted asm code?

Comment: Are you sure it is the random number generation and not the shuffle? Better post a [mcve] tailored to your question.

Comment: Also check the headers. libstdc++ has some preprocessor conditionals to compile different code for later versions of the compiler or to support C++11/C++17. Or they're configured to use different versions of libstdc++.

Comment: I would have to dig into the source code to confirm so just posting this as a comment: `std::shuffle` most like uses a `std::uniform_int_distribution` inside it to limit the generator to the range it has to work on.  `std::uniform_int_distribution` is required to give a specific probability but it is not required to give a total order.  If GCC changed it then that would explain the different results.

Comment: I suspect this is a difference in implementation of `std::shuffle`, did you check the sequence of pure random numbers generated between the two versions?

Comment: @NathanOliver It seems like a difference in `std::shuffle` implementation: https://wandbox.org/permlink/B6YhjG9IKpIlczNa vs. https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q9as1C8cTTG6Gbqf

Comment: Gee, thanks for the input everyone, I'll know which paths to wander down next time I run into something like this. Oh that's an excellent website @Bob__ , thanks for the reference.